# Join two tables and concat columns using Pyspark (databricks)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two tables in my database. I need to perform left outer join on these two tables with condition **table1.id = table2.id** also, source should match

Below are my two source tables.

Table 1 :

```
`source    id        type `

  eu2   10000162      N4    
  sus   10000162      M1    
  pda   10000162      XM
```

Table 2 :

```
`source   id         code1        code2`

  eu2   10000162        CDNG_GRP     PROB_CD
  sus   10000162        AANV          NW
  pda   10000162        PM2          VLPD
```

Expected output :

`source     id          type   concat`

```
  eu2   10000162      N4    CDNG_GRP-PROB_CD
  sus   10000162      M1    AANV-NW
  pda   10000162      XM    PM2-VLPD
```

I want this result in Dataframe.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, you need to perform join on the `source` and `id`  columns.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...
df = df1.join(df2, on=['id', 'source'], how='left') \
    .withColumn('concat', F.concat('code1', F.lit('-'), 'code2')) \
    .select(['source', 'id', 'type', 'concat'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark always returns a dataframe (until specified not to do so)

Try this:
Considering your tables are already spark dataframe

```
left_join = table1.join(table2, table1.id==table1.id, "leftouter")
left_join.show()
```